# Why do j need to be smaller or equal to sqrt(i)?

Tags: c++

I need to write a c++ program to find prime number within the range. But I don't know what the meaning of this code: `j<=sqrt(i)`

```
int main() {
    int num1,num2;
    int fnd=0,ctr=0;

    cout << "enter first number: ";
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "Enter second number: ";
    cin >> num2;

    for(int i=num1;i<=num2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=2;j<=sqrt(i);j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
                ctr++;
        }
        if(ctr==0&&i!=1)
        { fnd++;
            cout<<i<<" ";
            ctr=0;
        }
        ctr=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably better to think about attributes of a composite number - it has at least one factor other than itself and `1`.    For every factor less than or equal to `sqrt(i)` there will be another factor greater than or equal to `sqrt(i)` and vice versa.    If  no factor is found that is less than or equal to `sqrt(i)`, there cannot be a factor that is greater than or equal to `sqrt(i)`.    (And, if `sqrt(i)` is a factor of `i`, it is because it can be multiplied by itself to give `i`).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you want to check whether the number `25` is a prime number.

if you will write like

```
for ( int j = 2; j < sqrt( 25 ); j++ )
{
    //...
}
```

then you will get that `25` is a prime number! It is because `j` equal to `5` (and `5 * 5` yields `25`) does not take part in the iterations of the loop. For `j` equal to `5` the condition `j < sqrt( 25 )` evaluates to false.

So in the loop you have to write

```
for ( int j = 2; j <= sqrt( 25 ); j++ )
                   ^^
{
    //...
}
```

It is evident that for numbers that are greater `sqrt( 25 )` there will be a remainder. So there is no sense to continue the loop for divisors greater than `sqrt( 25 )`.

Pay attention that the loop is inefficient. You could initially check whether the given number is even and is not equal to 2. In this case it is obviousd that the number is not a prime number.

If the number is not even then you could apply a loop like

```
for ( int j = 3; j <= num / j; j += 2 )
```

Also if the number is equal to `1` then it is not a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

Lets think that you have number 100, and you need to find if it is prime or not. The number is prime if it can only be divided on 1 and on itself. So if we have 100, than on every number bigger than `sqrt(100)` (e.g. 10) that 100 can be divided the result will be in range from 1 to 10 (`sqrt(100)`). And as you don't need to find all divisors of number, but only one that is other than 1 and the number (in that way you can know if the number is not prime), so you are looping from 2 to `sqrt(number)`